# Setting mc size on stage yields weird x,y

Tags: flash, properties, size, movieclip, flash-cs3

I have an empty movie clip instance on stage with x=y=w=h=0.0. Anytime I try to set a non-zero width or height in the properties palette, the corresponding x or y value goes insanely huge, sometimes negative. When I lock the padlock, and set width to 1.0, the other goes like "-1.$".

While I know I can do lots of thing in AS, I'm a bit irritated by this bug. Does anyone know how to bust it?

Thx

Comment: By all means do NOT post any code. I much prefer to guess at where your bug is.

Comment: Got your sarcasm, but it's just out-of-place. The bug occurs with no action script as well so I have nothing to post. Go ahead and guess.

Comment: :) does the "Bug" happen at author-time or run-time?

Comment: Try moving your registration point

Comment: Is the movieclip scaled?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a movie the default registration point is the center of the movie clip.
When you change the width and height of the movie clip it will change the width and height according to the registration point
To change the point.
1) edit movie in the library
2) press cntrl+a to select all objects inside the movie clip.
3) move the objects to the circle is positioned in the upper left of all the objects.
4) close out of editing the movie.
5) now try to resize and X and Y will not change.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I pinned down the problem. My goal was to prepare a MovieClip container for externally loaded content, hence it did not contain any objects during author time. Apparently this causes problem for the IDE when trying to resize something which is empty. It is then also problematic to select such an object. So I resolved it by simply putting a background rectangle symbol in it.